# XSLT to replace a section

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to replace a section in XML using XSLT.

**Input:**

```
<data>
    <entry>
       <id>1</id>
       <propertyA>10</propertyA>
       <propertyB>20</propertyB>
    </entry>
    <entry>
       <id>2</id>
       <propertyA>8</propertyA>
       <propertyB>12</propertyB>
    </entry>
</data>
```

**Expected Output:**

```
<data>
    <entry>
       <id>1</id>
       <propertyA>15</propertyA>
       <propertyB>8</propertyB>
    </entry>
    <entry>
       <id>2</id>
       <propertyA>8</propertyA>
       <propertyB>12</propertyB>
    </entry>
</data>
```

I'm planning to do this using XSLT copy all nodes, but skip the target entry & generate them in place with new values.

As the first step, I wrote a XSLT to skip the target entry.

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/data/entry">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="id=$replaceId"></xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

But I'm getting the following output when $replaceId = 1 - entry element is missing. I understand that the `xsl:apply-templates` in my template matching `entry` is causing this. But, I'm not sure how to tackle this. An hour of searching in web didn't help me. I believe, SO folks can help me out.

```
<data>
       <id>2</id>
       <propertyA>8</propertyA>
       <propertyB>12</propertyB>
</data>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `entry` element is missing from your output because you do not copy it to the output. Additionally, in the case where the "when" condition is met:

```
<xsl:when test="id=$replaceId"></xsl:when>
```

the child nodes of this `entry` element are not processed at all.

In general, it is better to take advantage of separate templates rather than relying on `xsl:choose`. The elements `propertyA` and `propertyB` are the ones you really want to modify - so it would be best to write templates that match them directly.

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="replaceID" select="'2'"/>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="propertyA[parent::entry/id = $replaceID]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="15"/>
        </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="propertyB[parent::entry/id = $replaceID]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="8"/>
        </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <entry>
       <id>1</id>
       <propertyA>15</propertyA>
       <propertyB>8</propertyB>
    </entry>
    <entry>
       <id>2</id>
       <propertyA>8</propertyA>
       <propertyB>12</propertyB>
    </entry>
</data>
```